# Is there a way to get the stack name of the current active screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a set of stack navigators in each tabs of tab navigator. When I log the state of the navigation, within any component, i get following payload,

```
    import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    console.log(navigation.getState())

    // console.log result
    {
        "index": 1,
        "key": "stack-5XO-MpDH2pNKUKeoe1hoF",
        "routeNames": [
            "CHome",
            "CDetailPage",
            "CSPage"
        ],
        "routes": [
            {
                "key": "CHome-S99nM512YJSMqjIHj7lPt",
                "name": "CHome",
                "params": [
                    null
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "CSPage-ugZ8nf9H0B_H8jfrc1KNi",
                "name": "CSPage",
                "params": [
                    null
                ]
            }
        ],
        "stale": false,
        "type": "stack"
    }
```

From here, I can get the active route name and params, but how can i get in which stack does the current screen exists ?

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen>
    name="Home" <-------- If the above stack is this, then how to get this name withing any active screen( or from header ) ? 
    component={HomeStack}
  <Tab.Screen>
```

Is it possible to get the active tab name from a screen of a stack navigator ?

Comment: Would be very useful!